# Como cambiar valores de base de datos al pasar un día

Tags: sharedpreferences

soy nuevo en esto y estoy realizando una APK q trabaja con base de datos y requiero q cada vez que pase un día, los valores de toda una columna de la base de datos cambie, lo de hacer el cambio en la base de datos ya lo tengo, y obtener la fecha actual también, y almacenar el valor de la fecha en la sharedPreferences tambien, solo necesito saber cómo actualizar el valor de la fecha vieja con el actual para poder comparar al día siguiente. 
Me
Uso el siguiente código para lo de las preferencias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, por favor realiza el [tour] para que conozcas el funcionamiento del sitio. [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/268481/edit) la pregunta y cambia la imagen y coloca el código directamente en la pregunta. Revisa [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví, quitando el onDestroy y actualizando el valor de la variable guardada en el sharedPreferences y volviendo a llamar el método saveValuesPreferences en el onCreate[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]